# SharePoint online search api issue, unable to filter documents that are pending approval using crawled properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, enterprise-search, sharepoint-search

I've created a page that shows documents that are pending approval from different sites(content approval in libraries).

I configured a managed property `RefinableString01` and `RefinableInt01` and mapped it to the crawled property `ows__ModerationStatus`.

In the search page, I tried using `RefinableString01:'0'`, `RefinableInt01:0` etc. This query doesn't work consistently.

It brings documents that are pending approval from various sites, but it also sometimes keeps showing documents that are in approved state!

Initially I thought its just due to the delay in Crawling but this keeps happening and even after waiting for 24-48 hours and re-indexing the library and site, few approved document keeps showing up.

Can we use the crawled property `ows__ModerationStatus` and `_ModerationStatus` and use them in queries by mapping to mapped properties? or is it not possible to show documents that are pending approval in SharePoint online

Answer (score 1):

After you map RefinableInt01 to the crawled property ows__ModerationStatus, you may need to go to site settings > Search and offline availability > Reindex Site, and go to related library > library settings > Advanced settings > Reindex Document library

What's more, per my test, if we want to search for pending approval files, we need to use RefinableInt01:2

Here is my test result

[image]

[image]